# SWIFTUI warning imagePickerController nearly matches - happens only in existing swift project file

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiimagepickercontroller, imagepicker

I'm upgrading an existing app with some swift views. Now I'm getting the warning:

> Instance method 'imagePickerController(*:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'imagePickerController(*:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)' of protocol 'UIImagePickerControllerDelegate'

at the function:

```
public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
        if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            self.onImagePicked(image)
        }
       
        self.onDismiss()
    }
```

Additionally I get the error message:

> Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'originalImage'

The funny thing is, if I copy the code in a new project everything is fine (no warning, no error). In order to check whether I may have some effects from other views/methods within the existing project, I copied my existing project and deleted all other files, except the one with the imagepicker - still the warning and the error.

Is there any setup or other issue which might be the reason? Any help is more than appreciated - working on that the third day now ....

The whole code is:

```
import SwiftUI

public struct ImagePickerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    private let sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType
    private let onImagePicked: (UIImage) -> Void
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode

    public init(sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType, onImagePicked: @escaping (UIImage) -> Void) {
        self.sourceType = sourceType
        self.onImagePicked = onImagePicked
    }

    public func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = self.sourceType
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }

    public func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: Context) {}

    public func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(
            onDismiss: { self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() },
            onImagePicked: self.onImagePicked
        )
    }

      public class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

        private let onDismiss: () -> Void
        private let onImagePicked: (UIImage) -> Void

        init(onDismiss: @escaping () -> Void, onImagePicked: @escaping (UIImage) -> Void) {
            self.onDismiss = onDismiss
            self.onImagePicked = onImagePicked
        }
        
         public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
            if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                self.onImagePicked(image)
            }
            print("vor dismiss")
            self.onDismiss()
        }
        
        public func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_: UIImagePickerController) {
            self.onDismiss()
        }

    }

}
```

The project Format is Xcode 12.0-compatible, iOS Deployment Target is 14.0,
The project includes originally also watch

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer, can't explain but instead of

```
 public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
```

it works fine with

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
```

The problem is solved, however, if anyone could explain - more than welcome